# Zoom dependent layers in leaflet

Tags: leaflet

My leaflet map has two WMS layers with different scales; one of them is a 4cm topographic map. I would like to have both WMS on the map but showing only the topographic map when the zoom of the map is sufficient to read something.
Currently I use the minZoom / maxZoom attributes in order to switch when zoom 8 is reached:

```
var topo4cm =L.tileLayer.wms(topoaddress, {
    service: "WMS", transparent: !1, minZoom: 8, maxZoom: 18
});
var carto=L.tileLayer(cartoaddress, {
        minZoom: 0, maxZoom: 7, zoom:function() {
            var e=map.getZoom();
            return 10>e?"L0"+e: "L"+e
        }
    });
```

This does what I want: when zoom = 8, the topo map is shown. 
However the other layer (carto) cannot be manually switched in the panel control.
Would there be a way to allow the user to manually switch back to carto?

Comment: Can you clarify your question.  Do you want the user to be able to optionally see the carto layer when the zoom level is > 8?

Comment: Exactly. As it is, when I reach level zoom 8 and beyond, the baselayer changes. But since I have also put the layers in a control layer, I can still select 'carto', but obviously there is no more data (since the max zoom is 7). The carto layer would still be relevant to see because both of them are from different dates.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manually control the visibility of the layer without relying (only) on `minZoom` and `maxZoom`, for example:

```
map.on('zoom', function(){
    var z = map.getZoom();

    if (z > 0 && z < 8) {
        return carto.addTo(map);
    }

    if (someManualControlIsActive) {
        return carto.addTo(map);
    }

    return carto.removeFrom(map);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That's perfect since I also wanted to change some style of the overlay :)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to have a *single* WMS tile layer, and change the **layers** property based on the zoom level, you could use a custom tile layer like this one. It changes the `wmsParams.layers` dynamically based on the zoom level.

```
L.CustomWmsTileLayer = L.TileLayer.WMS.extend({
  createTile(coords, done) {
    if (coords.z !== this.lastZoomLevel) {
      this.lastZoomLevel = coords.z;
      if (typeof this.options.getLayersByZoomLevel === 'function') {
        this.wmsParams.layers = this.options.getLayersByZoomLevel(coords.z);
      }
    }
    return L.TileLayer.WMS.prototype.createTile.call(this, coords, done);
  },
});

L.customWmsTileLayer = function (url, options) {
  return new L.CustomWmsTileLayer(url, options);
};

// Use like this:
L.customWmsTileLayer('https://nonna-geoserver.data.chs-shc.ca/geoserver/wms', {
      layers: 'nonna:NONNA 10',
      getLayersByZoomLevel: (zoom) => (zoom < 12 ? 'nonna:NONNA 100' : 'nonna:NONNA 10'),
      format: 'image/png',
      transparent: true,
      attribution:
        '&copy; <a href="https://open.canada.ca/data/en/dataset/d3881c4c-650d-4070-bf9b-1e00aabf0a1d">CHS NONNA Bathymetric Data</a>',
});
```